# navigate to subroute defined in other component in angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

In my application we have created routing in app.component.ts file as follows.

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/dashboard/...', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
])
```

and created routing in Dashboard component for sub pages in dashboard like inbox,archives etc.

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path:'/inbox', name: 'Inbox', component: InboxComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path:'/outbox', name: 'Outbox', component: OutboxComponent},
    {path:'/profile', name: 'MyProfile', component: MyProfileComponent}
])
```

Now i have created header component which is common in dashboard.
and i am trying to navigate from header component to 'dathboard/profile'

I have tried

```
this.router.navigate(['Dashboard/MyProfile']);
```

But that is only changing URL in browser URL box but not redirecting to the component.

I am new to angular 2. Need help to resolve this navigation isssue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
this.router.navigate(['/ Dashboard', 'MyProfile']);
```

Ensure you have `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` only added once at the root component (or alternatively in `bootstrap()`.

Comment: Do you have `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` added at more than one place (root component or `bootstrap(...)`?

Comment: Yes in header component.
removed it and its working now.

its third time you saved me Günter.
You are boss.